# open workbook and after open it goes back to the beginning of sub,

Tags: vba

```
Option Explicit
Sub DleteColumns()

Dim objWorkbook As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim keepColumn As Boolean
Dim currentColumn As Integer
Dim columnHeading As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

'This is temporary for testing this one below

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    currentColumn = 1
    'open the workbook with data
    DoEvents
    Set objWorkbook = Workbooks.Open( _
    "H:\C_Files\xls\a_C_Track_20171101.xls")
    'Do a pause
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    'Stop
    'read the data from the first columns
    For i = 1 To 1

    currentColumn = 1
        While currentColumn <= ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
            columnHeading = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value

         'CHECK WHETHER TO KEEP THE COLUMN
            keepColumn = False

            If columnHeading = "#reason" Then keepColumn = True
            If columnHeading = "first_name" Then keepColumn = True
            If columnHeading = "last_name" Then keepColumn = True
            If columnHeading = "employer_name" Then keepColumn = True
            If columnHeadimg = "city" Then keepColumn = True
            If columnHeading = "state" Then keepColumn = True
            If columnHeading = "date_of_birth" Then keepColumn = True
            If columnHeading = "ssn" Then keepColumn = True

            If keepColumn Then
                currentColumn = currentColumn + 1
            Else
                ActiveSheet.Columns(currentColumn).Delete
            End If

            'LASTLY AN ESCAPE IN CASE THE SHEET HAS NO COLUMNS LEFT
             If (ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address = "$A$1") And 
                 (ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1").text = "") Then Exit Sub
        Wend

           Next i
     Stop
    'ActiveWorkbook.Save
    'objWorkbook.Close
     ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    End Sub
```

Comment: You should explain what you want to do, what you've tried, what you expect to happen, and what actually happens. Code dumps by themselves aren't helpful.

Comment: What is your question? Check this post first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you very much, I am new to vba, and couldn't figure out where to put the question, just the code... I am trying to open a workbook and delete about 50 columns, except the ones in the vba, whenever the code hits the open the workbook, it will open it and then jump back to the set.(where the open is), or if I put the stop in there, it will get past the open but won't execute the delete. I have looked at numerous sites, for a solution and they have an issue for the shift key, but I am not using the shift key.... thank you, for your response and your help is much appreciated.

Comment: The open is opening the workbook but then... nothing else executes, thank you, very much, for your response.

Comment: Are you running the macro?  Or are you single-stepping through the macro using F8?  (F8 will act as an F5 when it hits a `Workbooks.Open` command so you need to put a breakpoint on the line after, or use a `Stop` statement, if you want to continue single-stepping.)

Comment: Why do you even open the other workbook?  You never seem to use `objWorkbook` anywhere and, due to the `ThisWorkbook.Activate`, all your code is specifically targetting the active sheet in the workbook containing the macros.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I set objWorkbook, to the file that I am opening, I was under the impression that it was 'ThisWorkbook'... what should I do... I thought I was making it focus on the objWorkbook... I put the pause in there, because I thought i needed time to open? I appreciate your feedback... every bit of it... thank you...I thank you in advance...

Comment: I have been trying to run it via f5 and then when it didn't work i was running it  via f8. . I will take out  the stop and replace it with a breakpoint. I will also get rid of Do Events, application. wait ... and the thisworkbook.activate and see how it works..

Comment: Thank you.I took everything out, that was   requested  and it finished and deleted the columns.   i was reading different forums and putting things in the code, because it stopped working and was working before. It is working again now..Will you please elaborate on why ThisWorkbook.Activate is not a good idea? thanks to all.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Activate` activates `ThisWorkbook` (the workbook containing the running macro).  So the `ActiveSheet` is no longer in the newly opened workbook, it is in `ThisWorkbook`.  Therefore all your `ActiveSheet` references are referencing the active sheet in the workbook containing the macros.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, your only real problem is that, due to the `ThisWorkbook.Activate` statement, you are currently applying the changes to the active sheet in the workbook containing the macros.  Just removing that single line would probably mean your macro would work as you want it to.

However, the constant referencing of `ActiveSheet` is not a good idea.  The following code changes that so that it uses your `ws` object.  Although the code is still setting `ws` to be `ActiveSheet` (and thus still not particularly good in my opinion, as the `ActiveSheet` will be whichever sheet was active when the workbook was last saved) I have included in comments a couple of alternate ways of setting it that may be more appropriate.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DleteColumns()

    Dim objWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim keepColumn As Boolean
    Dim columnHeading As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'open the workbook with data
    Set objWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("H:\C_Files\xls\a_C_Track_20171101.xls")

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    'Better than the above line would be something like
    'Set ws = objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet_I_want_to_process")
    'or maybe
    'Set ws = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    With ws
        'Loop through each column in the sheet, working from right to left
        For i = .UsedRange.Columns(.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column To 1 Step -1
            columnHeading = .Cells(1, i).Value

            'CHECK WHETHER TO KEEP THE COLUMN
            keepColumn = False

            If columnHeading = "#reason" Then keepColumn = True
            If columnHeading = "first_name" Then keepColumn = True
            If columnHeading = "last_name" Then keepColumn = True
            If columnHeading = "employer_name" Then keepColumn = True
            'Ensure you type your variable names correctly - "columnHeadimg" in your
            'code would have stopped your program running
            If columnHeading = "city" Then keepColumn = True
            If columnHeading = "state" Then keepColumn = True
            If columnHeading = "date_of_birth" Then keepColumn = True
            If columnHeading = "ssn" Then keepColumn = True

            If Not keepColumn Then
                .Columns(i).Delete
            End If
        Next

        'Only save if there is something left
        If .UsedRange.Address <> "$A$1" Or .Range("$A$1").Text <> "" Then
            objWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
        End If
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub
```